# How to create a new process in C/C++ and get this new process handle in WinXp?

Tags: c++, c, windows, process

I need to know how to get a handle of a newly created process in C/C++ code. I don't know much about all those Microsoft libraries and I've just read about 2 ways to create a process. First is via ShellExcecute call and the second via CreateProcess but none of these retern a HANDLE. I need to know a handle of the process because I want the main thread to wait for process to finish before it continues. Best of all I'd like if someone help me write a function which looks like this:

```
HANDLE create_process(/*parameters same as for ShellExecute*/)
{
    ...
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateProcess()` returns a `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure which contains the process handle. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Whilst `ShellExecute()` does not give you the information that you need, `ShellExecuteEx()` returns the process handle in the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I would suggest that you look at the MSDN documentation for the API functions that you're using as it's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateProcess` returns the handle to the process in `PROCESS_INFORMATION`.